# Electron (Windows) not showing the menu when tray icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

Im want to create a tray app, before all Im trying to create a simple icon showing a menu with radios inputs to test Electron tray apps exact how the doc example shows up. But when i click on the icon nothing happening.

```js
const { app, Menu, Tray } = require('electron')
const { resolve } = require('path')


app.on('ready', () => {
    createTray()
})

const createTray = () => {
    const tray = new Tray(resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'tray-icon.png'))

    const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        { label: 'Item1', type: 'radio' },
        { label: 'Item2', type: 'radio' },
        { label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true },
        { label: 'Item4', type: 'radio' }
    ])
    tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)


    // using this to check if the click event is working
    tray.on('click', () => {
        console.log('clicked')
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the "clicked" log message? Since this is on the main process, this will be logged to the command prompt from where you start the app.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, the menu normally opens with a *right click* on the tray icon.

You can also trigger it by using [`tray.popUpContextMenu()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/tray#traypopupcontextmenumenu-position-macos-windows) in the `click` event handler that you have.

```js
tray.on("click", ()=>{
    tray.popUpContextMenu();
});
```